# Gradle dependencies change from http to https

Tags: gradle

I have added UI link dependency in my Gradle build

Getting the following error

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/ullink/gradle/gradle-repositories-plugin/1.1/gradle-repositories-plugin-1.1.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.ullink.gradle:gradle-repositories-plugin:1.1'
}
```

how can I change the target from "http" to "https"?

Comment: What version of Gradle do you use and how does the `repositories` block of your `build.gradle` look like?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`mavenCentral()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler:mavenCentral()) function in `dependencies` block in Gradle.

> Adds a repository which looks in the Maven central repository for dependencies. The URL used to access this repository is `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/`.

It must be HTTPs if you use `mavenCentral()`, but it's actually not. So, you probably don't use `mavenCentral()` (but should) and entered the HTTP URL manually. Make sure to use `mavenCentral()`, and not `maven()` with a manually edited URL.